# Why isn't the lowercase L being rendered on Windows 10 applications?

Tags: windows, windows-10, fonts, font-smoothing

This effect happens on system applications that (seem) to be using the default font.

In line 9, 10, 11 you can see L missing in "Film", and on line 13 in "Phenomenological", and so on.

This also appears on context menus in certain applications too. Often the obscure software, so not browsers or IDEs or Adobe software for example.

I have tried resetting the ClearType and that still did not solve the issue. I wonder if there has been some kind of "font renderer" installed on this machine that is causing this error, is there a way to find out?

[image]

Comment: It is rendering just fine on my system.  What font is that specifically?

Comment: I have no idea, I am just assuming it to be the default font as it doesn't happen on my IDEs or Browsers where the font is different. It seems to also appear in menu bars and toolbars, I can provide more examples if needed.

Comment: Check what you have assigned Windows to use?

Comment: Apparently no default value is set: http://i.imgur.com/q24fu53.png

Comment: So set one?  Verify what font is being used in the screenshot.

Comment: I have tried to play around with these settings in the registry but nothing is changing. Although, I don't want to -change- this font, I want to keep this font.. :P

Comment: Even if the font is at fault, the font you can't identify, you have to be willing to solve or at least provide us information so your question can be answered.  Worth pointing out the "l" in title is being rendered without a problem.  This source text appears to be from a OCR scan is that the case?

Comment: I can't identify it because I don't know how to, any help here would be appreciated

Comment: You can't open the spreadsheet and tell me what font is being used?  If that really is the case I will just go ahead and delete my comments.

Comment: It's not a spreadsheet, it's a system application, [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) to be specific.